# js реализация подписки, отписки и оповещения о событии

Tags: javascript, node.js

Салют всем! Начал изучать js и столкнулся с проблемой при решении одной задачи.
Что имеется

1. задание
2. файл проверки checks.js
3. реализация задания index.js

УСЛОВИЕ
В библиотеке нужно реализовать три метода:

- on — подписка на событие;
- off — отписка от события;
- emit — оповещение всех подписчиков.

Метод `off`:

Отписывает от события подписчика. После отписки, при возникновении данного события, никаких обработчиков, связанных с этим подписчиком, не должно быть вызвано. Есть возможность повторно подписаться и снова получать события.

Метод `on`:

Подписывает на событие. На любое событие подписчик может подписаться неограниченное количество раз.

Метод `emit`:

Оповещение всех подписчиков (не отписавшихся). Вызывает все функции-обработчики в порядке подписки.

Есть также расширенная проверка задания на стороне сервера - один пункт из которых я никак не могу пройти. а именно

```
6 of 7 tests passed.
```

Failed tests: не должен уведомлять отписанных

Не могу разобраться почему возникает такая ошибка - ведь в функции .off происходит удаление пользователей события... 
натолкните на мысль, где я заблудился)

**checks.js**

```
    // Встроенный в Node.JS модуль для проверок
    var assert = require('assert');

    // Подключаем свою функцию
    var emitter = require('./index.js');

    // Определим объект для счетчика нотификаций
    var notifications = {
        counter: 0,
        count: function () {
            this.counter++;
        }
    };

    // Определим для хранения логов
    var logger = {
        logs: []
    };

    // Подписываемся на событие new_notification и сразу оповещаем всех подписчиков
    emitter
        .on('new_notification', notifications, notifications.count)
        .on('new_notification', logger, function () {
            this.logs.push('Произошло новое событие new_notification');
        })
        .on('new_notification', logger, function () {
            // this указывает на logger
            this.logs.push('Добавлена новая нотификация. Количество - ' + notifications.counter);
        })
        .emit('new_notification');
    // Проверяем количество нотификаций
    assert.equal(notifications.counter, 1, 'Получена одна нотификация');

    // В логе сохранено событие
    // Так как обработчик notifications.count отработал первым,
    //  в логах сохранено правильное количество нотификаций
    assert.deepEqual(logger.logs, [
        'Произошло новое событие new_notification',
        'Добавлена новая нотификация. Количество - 1'
    ]);

    // На время отключаем логгирование, а затем снова включаем
    emitter
        .on ('new_notifications', logger, function () {
            this.logs.push('new one')
        })
        .off('new_notifications', logger)
        .off('new_notification', logger)
        .emit('new_notification')
        .on('new_notification', logger, function () {
            this.logs.push('Новое событие new_notification!');
        })
        .emit('new_notification');

    // Проверяем количество нотификаций
    assert.equal(notifications.counter, 3, 'Получено три нотификации');
    // Проверяем, что логи были отключены, а затем снова подключены

    assert.deepEqual(logger.logs, [
        'Произошло новое событие new_notification',
        'Добавлена новая нотификация. Количество - 1',
        'Новое событие new_notification!'
    ]);
emitter
    .on('new_notification', logger, function () {
        this.logs.push('Произошло новое событие new_notification')
    })
    .off ('new_notifications', logger)
    .emit('new_notifications');

assert.equal(notifications.counter, 3, 'Получено три нотификации');

    console.info('OK!');
```

**index.js**

```
    module.exports = {
    //свойство, в котором все события
subs: {}, //объект отвечающий за события
/**
 * @param {String} event
 * @param {Object} subscriber
 * @param {Function} handler
 */
on: function (event, subscriber, handler) { //подписка пользователя на событие
    if(!this.subs.hasOwnProperty(event)){ //проверка наличия события
        this.subs[event] = []; //если событие несуществует, создаем соответсвующее свойство объекта
    }
    this.subs[event].push({
        subscriber: subscriber,
        handler: handler.bind(subscriber)
    });
    return this;
},
/**
 * @param {String} event
 * @param {Object} subscriber
 */
off: function (event, subscriber) {//удаление пользователя и функции события
    if(this.subs.hasOwnProperty(event)){
        for( let i = this.subs[event].length -1; i >=0 this.subs[event].length; --i){

            if(this.subs[event][i].subscriber === subscriber){
                this.subs[event].splice(i, 1);
            }

        }
        return this;
    }
    return this;
},
/**
 * @param {String} event
 */
emit: function (event) { //оповещение, задействоание фукнции события
    if(this.subs[event] != undefined){

    for( let i = 0; i < this.subs[event].length; i++){
        this.subs[event][i].handler();
    }
}
    return this;
}
};
```

Спасибо все, кто примет участие!

Comment: Это точно все тесты? В приведенном файле вижу только 4 теста.

Comment: соглашусь с Вами, изменил это решение, однако влияние на прохождение теста не получил. Это не все тесты - есть проверка на стороне сервера сайта - я вижу лишь результат проверки, а именно 
6 of 7 tests passed.
Failed tests: не должен уведомлять отписанных
Какой именно тест проводит анализатор, не могу узнать...

Comment: Добавьте в свои тесты проверку на отписку. Наример после в конце после всех тестов отпишите notifications, потом сделайте emit, а потом проверьте чтобы нотификаций было все еще три assert.equal(notifications.counter, 3, 'Получено три нотификации');
Так вы сможете вручную продебажить ваш метод off. Пока что вы его никак не тестируете, а сервер тестирует и находит ошибку.

Comment: Добавил проверку - каких то дополнительных ошибок не выявлено - все проходит...

Comment: Ок, а обновите, пожалуйста код в вопросе.

Comment: перед тем как залить вопрос сюда - я отслеживал поведение объекта subs при работе метода .off - путем вставки console.log(this.subs[event]) на каждом моменте итерации. Как я понял удаление проходит успешно и вопрос именно при каком таком специфеческом условии происходит сбой)

Comment: Все ли параметры у off() обязательны? возможно сервер тестирует emitter.off('event_name'), тогда если сабсркайбер не передается, вам нужно очищать весь массив this.subs[event].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотрим:

```
for( let i = 0; i < this.subs[event].length; i++){
  if(this.subs[event][i].subscriber === subscriber){
    this.subs[event].splice(i, 2);
  }
}
```

В этом коде вы меняете массив в цикле по этому же массиву. Это чревато - не надо так.

К тому же я не совсем понимаю, почему вы **удаляете сразу 2** подписчика.

Попробую продемонстрировать:

```js
let list = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 6
];

const debug = (i, list) => console.log(`iter#${i}: ${list}. Current: ${list[i]}`);


// Удаляем все чётные
debug(0, list);
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i, debug(i, list)) {
  if ((list[i] % 2) === 0) list.splice(i, 1);
}

// Удаляя один элемент, мы пропускаем не анализируя следующий.
// Теоретически может помочь декремент счётчика, но лучше так не делать - это многократно ухудшает читаемость кода

console.log(list+''); // 1,3,6
```

Есть несколько решений:

- изменить направление итерации
  `for (let i = this.subs[event].length - 1; i>=0; --i) { ... }`.

В этом случае удаление элементов в хвосте не влияет на последующие итерации.

- Заменять весь массив:
  `this.subs[event] = this.subs[event].filter(sub => sub.subscriber !==
  subscriber)`
- Исправлять счётчик цикла, чтобы он указывал на следующий элемент

```js
let orig = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6], list;

// исправленный счётчик
list = orig.slice(0);
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
  if ((list[i] % 2) === 0) list.splice(i--, 1);
}
console.log(list+''); // 1,3

// обратное направление цикла
list = orig.slice(0);
for (let i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  if ((list[i] % 2) === 0) list.splice(i, 1);
}
console.log(list+''); // 1,3

// замена всего массива
list = orig.slice(0);
list = list.filter(el => el % 2 !== 0);
console.log(list+''); // 1,3
```

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий - действительно, учел Ваше замечание! Благодарю за подробное объяснение - сразу стало понятно. Сам сомневался почему splice(i, 2) а не splice(i , 1). Теперь все встало на места - в коде поправил.  Однако пока что основной вопрос не ушел - все равно идет ошибка анализатора. Буду пробовать устранять другие замечания! Еще  раз благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте реализовать удаление всех сабскрайберов, если передан только эвент. Возможно сервер тестирует этот кейс.

```
if (event && subscriber !== undefined) {
    this.subs[event].length = 0;
}
```

Кстати возможно тестируется off и без параметров вовсе, тогда нужно очистить все subs:

```
if (event !== undefined && subscriber !== undefined) {
    this.subs = {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Список решений, которые мне помогли:

1) от пользователя [vp-arth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176064/vp-arth) благодаря нему был изменен кусок кода, отвечающий за итерацию по массиву. Он подробно объяснил причину, почему стоит использовать обратный счетчик, а также предложил ряд других альтернатив - исчерпывающе и понятно. Спасибо!

```
for( let i = this.subs[event].length - 1; i >= 0; --i){

        if(this.subs[event][i].subscriber === subscriber){
            this.subs[event].splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
```

2)от пользователя [mike-papou](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/300598/mike-papou) поступило предложение добавить проверку на наличие переданного объекта в метод, однако в итоговой версии, для валидатора понадобилось реализовать проверку на существование именно этого события в объекте хранящем события. Все равно считаю, что это идея повлияла на итоговое решение, спасибо!

```
if (this.subs[event] == undefined) {
```

Также появился ряд недочетов в коде, который мне подсказали на другом форуме. Наверное основное - обнуление длины массива:

```
else if(event && subscriber === undefined){
```

this.subs[event].length = 0;

Обнулив так длину, при следующей попытке отписаться, попав в следующую ветку if-а, итерация по массиву будет некорректной, т.к. она зависит от длины, которая 0, то есть банально не все элементы массива будут просмотрены.

Было принято решений поменять на метод splice, как более безопасный вариант

```
this.subs[event].splice(0, this.subs[event].length);
```

Финальная версия кода:

```
    module.exports = {
    //свойство, в котором все события
subs: {}, //объект отвечающий за события
/**
 * @param {String} event
 * @param {Object} subscriber
 * @param {Function} handler
 */
on: function (event, subscriber, handler) { //подписка пользователя на событие
    if(subscriber === undefined){
        return this;
    }else{
    if(!this.subs.hasOwnProperty(event)){ //проверка наличия события
        this.subs[event] = []; //если событие несуществует, создаем соответсвующее свойство объекта
    }
    this.subs[event].push({
        subscriber: subscriber,
        handler: handler.bind(subscriber)
    });
    return this;
}
},
/**
 * @param {String} event
 * @param {Object} subscriber
 */
off: function (event, subscriber) {//удаление пользователя и функции события
    if (this.subs[event] == undefined) {
        return this;
    }else if(this.subs.hasOwnProperty(event) && subscriber === undefined){
        this.subs[event].splice(0, this.subs[event].length);
        return this;
    }else{
        if(this.subs.hasOwnProperty(event)){

        for( let i = this.subs[event].length - 1; i >= 0; --i){

            if(this.subs[event][i].subscriber === subscriber){
                this.subs[event].splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        return this;
        }   
    }
},
/**
 * @param {String} event
 */
emit: function (event) { //оповещение, задействоание фукнции события
    if(this.subs[event] != undefined && this.subs[event].length > 0){

    for( let i = 0; i < this.subs[event].length; i++){
        this.subs[event][i].handler();
    }
}
 return this;
}
};
```

всем спасибо за участие!